# GWT: Calling a javascript function from Java

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, libgdx

Hi I am trying to call a function in a .js file from java.

In my Java code I have

```
@Override
public native void test()
/*-{
    //JAVASCRIPT
    $wnd.h8();
}-*/;
```

Just an Alert inside the method works but I can't call one of my functions. I've tryed $wnd, $doc and nothing.

Say I have a functions.js with this in it:

```
function h8(){
    alert("hi");
}
```

In my index I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
       <head>

              <title>GWT Test</title>
              <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
              <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
              <script src="js/functions.js"></script> 

       </head>

       <body>
              <div align="center" id="embed-html"></div>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="html/html.nocache.js"></script>
       </body>

</html>
```

So there you see I am loading the script file in the html, but I get the 'undefined is not a function' error. Whithout $doc or $wnd I get the Can't find variable h8 error.

This is the console error:

```
GwtApplication: exception: (TypeError) 
 line: 112978
 column: 10
 sourceURL: http://127.0.0.1:9876/html/52574FB8FF8725CA72DFF813B62FEE86.cache.js
 __gwt$exception: <skipped>: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$wnd.h8()')
(TypeError) 
 line: 112978
 column: 10
 sourceURL: http://127.0.0.1:9876/html/52574FB8FF8725CA72DFF813B62FEE86.cache.js
 __gwt$exception: <skipped>: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$wnd.h8()')
```

Comment: What happens if you call h8() in JS console?, I suppose you are doing, but can you check if you are calling the test() method in your entry point?

Comment: The test() is called from java because if I change $wnd.h8() for a simple alert("hey") it does the alert.

Comment: You didn't answer my first question does h8 works in dev console. I guess you are defining in other scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define Window function:

```
Window.h8 = function() {
    alert("!!!");
};
```

And access it with $wnd.

```
private static native void callFunction() /*-{
    $wnd.h8();
}-*/;
```

Comment: I call $wnd.h8(); from the Java test method and have Window.h8 = function(){ alert("hi"); }; in my js file and still undefined is not a function... [gwt$exception: <skipped>: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$wnd.h8()']

Comment: It was window.h8 with lower case. Thanks you both.